# Was the King of Spades targeting certain players?

Tags: alice-in-borderland

In the second series of Alice in Borderland the King of Spades is a constant threat for those not directly engaged in more cerebral games.

He usually seems to target the largest group of survivors he can find or anybody who attacks him but on one occasion he happens to kill a character just as they are about to reveal a revelation to another character who is recording the conversation:

> Namely that the fireworks on entering the Borderland might have been something else - probably a meteorite if the character knows what they are talking about.

Was this intentional or coincidental action from this citizen in suppressing the conversation? We are later shown a scene that suggests he might not be entirely in control of his actions:

> A flashback where he kills a comrade to end their suffering. If I am reading this correctly it suggests he had PTSD before he entered the Borderland which leads to his homicidal nature.